# SP2013 - Filtering not working on Calendar view of Task list

Tags: calendar, tasks, view, task-list, bug

I have a page with a Task list on it displaying its Calendar view. I have a filter on the Calendar view where it should only show items where "Show On Content Calendar" is equal to Yes, however the Calendar view is not filtering anything and all items are being displayed.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What type of field "Show On Content Calendar" is and how did you set the filter?

Comment: @MdMazzotti It is a Yes/No field. The filter was set on the Calendar view. Modify View -> Filter -> "Show On Content Calendar" is equal to "Yes". Regardless, I have tried other filtering just to test. I tried used the OOTB field Task Status, where is not equal to "Completed" and still get all items.

Comment: I just tried on my env just to make sure and I can confirm filters work as expected. there must be something on your side

Comment: @MdMazzotti You are using a Task list's Calendar view and not a Calendar list's Calendar view right? I had tried this with a new Task list and I get the same issue of filtering not working.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I was using a Calendar indeed. I tried with a Task list and filters don't work. So, it seems they managed to screw this up, as in SP2010 calendar views with filters for task lists were working properly

Comment: Yeah, this is a bug (wtf!) http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/53a7840c-5ffe-499e-933c-e93898beee54/sharepoint-server-2013-tasks-views-calendar-views-filtering-problem?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: In order to save someone else's time, this is a bug and [has already been reported](http://www.craiglussier.com/2013/02/22/sharepoint-2013-bug-task-list-calendar-view-filtering-with-today-or-me/).

Answer (score 1):

for me it was resolved after patching to 
 ​​​**15.0.4745.1001** - ​Aug  2015 - Cumulative update- [KB3055009](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3055009) .

it was SP1 - 15.0.4569.1000 - version before which have calendar filter view problems on task list views

Comment: I ran setup(KB3055009) for above problem, setup ran successfully and ask to reboot machine  but problem still persists.

Comment: @VishwanathMishra . Did you try to run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard for all servers in the farm after installing? are you seeing this exact version in Central Admin-> Manage Servers in the Farm?

Comment: No, I only restarted server machine after installing update. Did I need to run configuration wizard?

Comment: @VishwanathMishra. yes,of course. otherwise it is not applied on SharePoint only with installing the CU. as i said you can see the central admin and goes to "Manage Servers in the Farm" under "system setting" and see the Configuration database version and the "Status" column of servers and see if the Upgrade required or needed is written.

Comment: Under status column it is "No Action required", although I ran config wizard successfully but still Calendar view in Task List is still not working :-(

Comment: @VishwanathMishra. It is strange. my recommendation is updating to a more recent CU and also running the configuration wizard after that .

Comment: I gone thru the CU details, nowhere it mentioned that Calendar filter in Task List bug is fixed. Can u please suggest how to proceed next.

Comment: I do not now the reason, I have written my true story or maybe it was fixed because of some other reasons.